# Multiple of ten

Tags: javascript, html

`function glgm() { if(parsedAcc == 10) { accg.innerHTML = parsedAccG += 1; } }`

I just need to know how to replace the 10 by "multiple of ten" so that it works every time it gets to a multiple of ten thank you.
I'm learning so I don't know much. I'm sorry if it's obvious.

Comment: `parsedAcc % 10 == 0`